# Are Django redirect responses cached by default?

Tags: django, redirect

I have a url shortener and this is the view:

```
def reroute(request, shorthand, parameter=None):
    ....
    #constructs url
    url = ...
    return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(url)
```

Basically I take in a url `http://localhost:8000/silly-big-cat` and route that to whatever the user supplied when this was created. The behavior that I started to notice was that the browser would hit the server once, if I went to that link again the browser somehow remembers where it was redirected last time and I see no indication of it hitting the server. Is the browser somehow caching this? If this is the case, is there a way to prevent this caching from happening? silly-big-cat's URL might change in the future but the browser may still be stuck with the old URL.

Comment: I think the browser itself will normally cache permanent URLs yes. Although that depends from browser to browser. But the idea of a permanent redirect is to be, well, permanent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the browser somehow caching this?

Most browsers will indeed remember *permanent* redirects, and therefore not bother to first visit the URL and then follow the redirect.

> silly-big-cat's URL might change in the future but the browser may still be stuck with the old URL.

Do not make it permanent, but use a simple [**`HttpResponseRedirect`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect). This has as status code, if you do not pass `permanent=True`, 302, whereas a permanent one has HTTP response 301.